# journalctl: how to prevent text from truncating in terminal

Tags: terminal, systemd

How can I keep long strings from truncating in terminal?  For example if I run

`journalctl -xn`

There's a lot of text that I cannot read.  I am open to using other programs/tools.

Comment: Use `journalctl -x`, `-n` default to 10 lines in log only.

Comment: Who came up with the idea to truncate the output anyways?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

From the `journalctl` manpage:

```
   The output is paged through less by default, and long lines are
   "truncated" to screen width. The hidden part can be viewed by using the
   left-arrow and right-arrow keys. Paging can be disabled; see the
   --no-pager option and the "Environment" section below.
```

If you don't want to constantly be using the left and right arrow keys, simply pipe it directly to `less`:

```
$ journalctl -xn | less
```

This will wrap lines that are too long for your terminal (the default behavior of `less`, which `journalctl` overrides).

Or, of course, if you don't mind possibly having to use your terminal's scrollback, you could use no pager at all:

```
$ journalctl -xn --no-pager
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I saw.

Comment: This is really frustrating.  If pager is set to `less`, and `LESS` does not include `-S`, journalctl should not be applying `-S` to the invocation of `less`!!  That is, setting PAGER=less and LESS=$x (where $x is any string that does not contain S) should give the desired behavior.

Comment: That is, journalctl should honor LESS, and the user should not have to also set SYSTEMD_LESS!  (Apologies, doorknob, this is a bit of a rant that probably doesn't belong as a comment to your answer)

Comment: Silly William.  Mr. Pottering knows what's best for you, and if you don't like it, you are obviously wrong.</rant>

Comment: For colored output: `SYSTEMD_PAGER="less -r" journalctl -xn`

Comment: @V02460 what if I want to preserve journalctl colors after piping the output through `grep`?

Comment: @PabloA Prefixing `SYSTEMD_COLORS=true` helps.

Comment: the right answer to keep colors and wrap text is `SYSTEMD_LESS="FRXMK" journalctl` - note excluded S

Answer (score 31):

I also do:

```
journalctl -xn | less
```

But you can also set the `SYSTEMD_LESS` environment variable:

```
SYSTEMD_LESS=FRXMK journalctl -xn
# Or even
# SYSTEMD_LESS="" journalctl -xn
# The environment variable needs to be there, but can be the empty string
```

I got that from: [[systemd-devel] [PATCH] pager: wrap long lines by default](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-August/022227.html)

Set it in your .bashrc and be done with it! :-)

That `systemd` needs to setup `less` specially and doesn't just honor the less defaults and the `LESS` environment seems a little arrogant to me, but hey, this works...

Comment: SYSTEMD_LESS support is only recently added, e.g CentOS 7 does not have a version that supports it

Comment: Works at least on CentOS 7.5.

Comment: Great solution, I also added `Defaults env_keep += "LESS SYSTEMD_LESS"` to `/etc/sudoers`. It's for those times when I accidentally put `sudo` in front of e.g. `systemctl status`.

Comment: It's not merely "a little arrogant", it's incredibly annoying.  I hope it's not arrogance, but ignorance that drives this behavior.

Comment: Glanced at the source code.   Specifically overriding the user's choice in LESS is just plain stupid.  I'm still not sure if it's arrogance or ignorance, but probably a healthy combination of the two.

Comment: Hmmm. https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-February/016814.html

Answer (score 7):

If the program already uses `less` (if not, pipe the output to it), you can enable/disable line wrapping by typing `-S` (in `less`), This works for other `less` options as well.

Answer (score 5):

Note also that:

```bsh
journalctl -f
```

will show you all the latest as it comes in *and* wrap like any normal human being (or even sysadmin) would expect to allow easy reading, copy-pasting, and everything else.

Answer (score 2):

`$ SYSTEMD_PAGER="less +-S" journalctl`

`+` executes command on start and `-S` disable chopping.

You can also set this value for a session or save in rc/profile script.

Answer (score 1):

This is the command I use for CentOS 7, which preserves coloring and wraps lines:

```
SYSTEMD_PAGER="less -r"  journalctl
```

Answer (score -1):

I type in terminal,
`journalctl | more`, works great for me then I use arrows up or down.