# How to show streamed input with 'less'

Tags: less

I'd like to use `journalctl -f` and pass that content into `less` for the following reasons:

- Horizontal scrolling for long lines (instead of line wrapping)
- Easy vertical scrolling

So `less` works fine with static content (like a file or terminated streaming data), but can it also work with unterminated streaming data?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
journalctl -f | less -???
```

If I try this now, `less` will wait and not show any data until I press Ctrl+C, then it will show an empty file.

Edit: This is not about `tail -f` – tail can only read files from disk, not streaming data piped in from stdin.

Edit2: It's not just about `journalctl` alone. I'm using JSON output with `-o json` and pretty-print that using `jq`. This will be part of the pipeline, but was left out for simplicity of this question. If I can stream anything into `less`, I can also insert a formatter into the pipeline.

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229188/journalctl-how-to-prevent-text-from-truncating-in-terminal

Comment: Have you tried typing G?

Comment: G jumps to the end of the file. But in streaming, there is no end of a file, there isn't even a `less` because it's still sitting there waiting for the end of the stream that never happens because new data can arrive any time.